# How to convert a function based view into class based ListView?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-generic-views

How implement Django.views.generic if earlier used request?

```
    from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from .models import *
    from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
    from .forms import *
    from django.views.generic import ListView

# Create your views here.
# New 
    
    class HomePage(ListView):
        model = Book
        template_name = 'book/templates/home.html'

# Old      
    def home(request):
        books=Book.objects.all()
        context={'books':books}
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return render(request,'book/templates/adminhome.html',context)
        else:    
            return render(request,'book/templates/home.html',context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `ListView` in following way:

```py
class BookListView(ListView):
    model=Book
    context_object_name='books'
    
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            return ['book/templates/adminhome.html']
        else:
            return ['book/templates/home.html']
```

`Note:` Class based views requires their names to be written as model name as the prefix and actual view name as the suffix, so I changed it to `BookListView` from <s>`HomePage`</s>.